How can I execute build.gradle by running another .gradle file without modifying the build.gradle file?
ano.gradle:
apply from: 'build.gradle'

tasks.register('afterBuild') {
    doLast {
        println 'another gradle'
    }
}

I expect to execute build.gradle -> execute afterBuild by running .\gradlew -b ano.gradle, but I don't want to modify the build.gradle file. I can't achieve this. Could you suggest a good way to do it? Thank you!
